# How do I find the right SerialPort name?

Tags: java, arduino, serial-port

I want to read out some information from a Arduino over the serial port.

I use the jSerialComm library.

Here's my code:

```
SerialPort serialPort = SerialPort.getCommPort("COM3");
serialPort.setComPortParameters(9600, 8, 1, 0);

if(serialPort.isOpen())
{
  System.out.println("SerialPort is open");
}
else
{
  System.out.println("SerialPort is not open");
}
```

Sadly, the program says that the port is closed, but I know it's not. I guess that I named it wrong here: `SerialPort.getCommPort("COM3");` So how do I have to name it so it will work?

Comment: Your questions seems to be about java (and the serial library you're using)  
And about the type of Arduino "compatible" device.
My "nearly a Nano" could be identified by the name "USB-SERIAL CH340 (COM5)"

Comment: And where did you find this name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if any of this works (can't test atm), but I hope it does:

- You could maybe look up the name in Device Manager -> Ports;
- You can try running this and see what it says:

```java
SerialPort[] list= SerialPort.getCommPorts();
if (list.length == 0) {
  System.out.println("No ports found");
} else {
  for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Port " + i + ": " + list[i].getDescriptivePortName());
  }
}
```

- Or you could just try this and see what happens:

```java
SerialPort serialPort = SerialPort.getCommPorts()[3];
```

Also, have a look at your baudrates, try with the Serial Monitor closed, and try an other USB cable.

Comment: This `SerialPort serialPort = SerialPort.getCommPorts()[3];` seems not to work and the other thing gives me some information but I tryed every option I have. Like: `getSystemPortName` **COM3** | `getDescriptivePortName` **Serielles USB-Gerät (COM3)** | and  `getPortDescription`  **USBSER000**. I also looked in my Arduino IDE and tryed **COM3 (Arduino Uno)**

Comment: I would try that first line with many numbers instead of "3" before giving up 8-). What is the "some information"; what does the code list as ports and devices (all of them)? And no translation needed, I speak German.

Comment: Could it be that something is wrong here: `serialPort.setComPortParameters(9600, 8, 1, 0);` ? Because in my Device Manager stands 9600 but my serial Monitor and the arduino programm is set to 115200 baud

Comment: ok I set everything to 115200 baud: It don't worked. Then I set everything to 9600 and it still doesn't work :(

Comment: What ports does it show in Tools -> Port? Have you tried an other USB cable?

Comment: ohhhh I am so dumb the serial monitor was open in the background the whole time now it works :) But I have one question how do I read out what my programm writes in the serial monitor ?

Comment: By getting your Java program to work with the Serial Monitor closed? 8-) Don't forget to vote if you are so inclined.

Comment: yeah so my arduino writes stuff into the serial monitor and I don't know how to read this out with my java application. At the end I want to have a programm that creates a String in which the same stuff is written as my arduino is writing into the serial monitor

Comment: There are a great many coding examples using jSerialComm here: https://www.codota.com/code/java/classes/com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort . I don't know the library, and my Java is rusty, so I can't help you there.